# Visual Studio Nuget Install-Package Invalid URI: Invalid Port Specified

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

In VS2013 Package Manager Console, command Install-Package gives error
Invalid URI: Invalid Port specified
At line: 1 char:1
Category Info : Not specified: (:) [Install-Package], UriformatException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException, NuGet.Powershell.Commands.GetPackageCommand

Not using proxy. 
Where is the port specified that it is complaining about? How is this fixed? I looked at the other solutions in SO and none helped.